# how to handle exception in service-activator?

Tags: spring-integration

in my code i have a flow 
inbound-channel-adapter -> splitter -> router -> service-activator -> chain

i got some exception in service-activator, how can i write a errorHandler so that whenever exception occurs it will redirect to a errorHandler.

```html
<int:service-activator input-channel="input1" ref="startAction" method="processAction"  output-channel="processTransactionChannel" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add an `error-channel` to the inbound channel adapter (or its poller if it's polled).

You will get an `ErrorMessage` with a `MessagingException` payload with two properties `failedMessage` and `cause.

Comment: i added error-channel to poller to inbound channel <int:poller default="true" fixed-delay="150000" error-channel="exception" >, my error channel is .<int:chain input-channel="exception" output-channel="processedItems"  >
        <int:service-activator ref="errorLogger" method="logError"></int:service-activator>  
    </int:chain>  . it calls the logError method but it is not forwarding the request to output-channel="processedItems" .

Comment: Don't put code/config in comments; it's completely unreadable - edit your question instead and add a comment indicating you have done so. I am not sure what you mean by "forwarding the request"; the message sent to `processedItems` is whatever is returned by your `logError` method; if it returns void, the error flow ends.